# Parsing using Polars

Tags: python, parsing, numbers, python-3.6, python-polars

I am trying to load data into a polars DataFrame using the read_csv command but I keep getting this error

```
RuntimeError: Any(ComputeError("Could not parse 0.5 as dtype Int64 at column 13.\n                                            The total offset in the file is 11684833 bytes.\n\n                                            Consider running the parser `with_ignore_parser_errors=true`\n                                            or consider adding 0.5 to the `null_values` list."))
```

While I used the converters argument as follows:

```
converters = {
    'Date': lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%b %d, %Y"),
    'Number': lambda x: float(x)
    }
```

The error still persists.
I also tried to use the argument displayed in the error:

```
with_ignore_parser_errors=TRUE
```

The error is still there. What can I do?
My issue is not with parsing dates, but rather with parsing numbers.
This is what I have for now:

```
    converters = {
    'Date': lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%b %d, %Y"),
    'Number': lambda x: float(x)
    }
    df_file = pl.read_csv(file_to_read, has_headers=True, converters=converters,with_ignore_parser_errors=TRUE)
```

Comment: I also tried to use a function as the converter

def col_fixer(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return np.str

df_file = pl.read_csv(file_to_read, has_headers=True, converters=dict(B=col_fixer))

Answer (score 4):

Polars doesn't have a `converters` argument. So that won't work.

It seems that a floating point column is trying to be parsed as integers. You can manually set the `dtype` to `pl.Int64` by passing the column name as `kwargs`: `pl.read_csv(.., dtype = {"foo": pl.Int64}`.

Or you can increase the `infer_schema_length` so that polars automatically detects floats (the first 100 rows probably only contain integers).

The default is `100`, try increasing it until schema inference correctly detects the floating point column.